# Reading encrypted text in program in c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encryption, c++-cli

I need some help to decrypt my text file and make it able to read in my program..

What I have programmed so far is to read the encrypted file, create a new file, decrypt it and read the newly created file..

I need to decrypt the encrypted file without having to create a new file that reads the decrypted text..

Well, Let me show you my code:

P.S Most of the include is not needed and I already know that

Visual studio 2010 Windows Form Application CLR

```
#pragma once


#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>


namespace EncryptandDecryptfiletest {


using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;


private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


             /*Decryption --- When program loads*/


             char ch,mod;
             char key = 97;
             char name[100] = "Encrypted.txt";
             char target[100] = "TTO.txt";
             ifstream fin("Encrypted.txt", ios::binary); // Reading file
             if(!fin) //open the encrypted file in a binary mode
             {
                 MessageBox::Show("Encrypted.txt did not open"); //If file does not exist
             } //or any kind of error

             ofstream fout;
             fout.open(target,ios::binary); //Opens outputfile
             if(!fout)
             { //Show error if any error occurs in opening new file
                 MessageBox::Show("TTO.txt did not open");
             }
             while(fin.get(ch))
             { // opens the Encrypted file
                 if(ch==EOF)break;
                 mod = ch + key;
                 if (mod > 255 ) mod -= 255;
                 fout << mod; //Writes decrypted text to TTO.txt
             }
             fin.close(); //Close the encrypted file
             fout.close(); // Close the decrypted file
         }
private: System::Void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


             label1->Text = comboBox1->Text;
             pictureBox1->Load("Images\\" + comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString() + ".png");


             //String^ openFileTest = "Encrypted.txt"; // Opens the encrypted .txt file
             String^ openFileTest = "TTO.txt"; //Opens the newly created file that is decrypted


             try  //Reading the .txt file
             {
                 StreamReader^ DataIn = File::OpenText(openFileTest);
                 String^ DataStr;
                 int count = 0;
                 array<String^>^ result;
                 array<Char>^ separ = gcnew array<Char>{'"'}; //After each Quote gets a new value of result[x]


                 while((DataStr = DataIn->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
                 {
                     count++;
                     result = DataStr->Split(separ);
                     if(comboBox1->Text == result[0]) // result[0] = Name
                     {
                         textBox1->Text = result[1]; //reads first word in txt file
                         textBox2->Text = result[2]; //second word in txt file
                         textBox3->Text = result[3]; //third word in txt file
                     }
                 } // ends while()
             } // ends try
             catch (Exception^ e)
             {
                 if(dynamic_cast<FileNotFoundException^>(e))
                     MessageBox::Show("File " + openFileTest + " not found");
             }
         } // Ends comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged void
 };
}
```

You have my decryption code and the code I want to use..

I have uploaded the code for you to use on your computer because it is fairly hard for me to explain..

I want to be able to read the encrypted file in my program, without having to writing a new file to decrypt it..

I hope anyone is able to help me

Decrypted & Encrypted .txt file Included (And images)

--> Program .rar pack [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ejrcad19b4a4gfl/Xakzyy+Test+decrypt.rar) <--

Build it with Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the output file stream with a `MemoryStream`.

The first thing to do is decompose into functions. Since you read your streams byte per byte, you won't need readers, which is good.

```
void Decrypt(Stream^ input, Stream^ output)
{
    char key=97;
    int byteRead;
    while((byteRead=input->ReadByte()) >= 0)
    {
        char ch = (char)byteRead;
        char mod = (char)(ch+key)
        output->WriteByte(mod);
    }
}

//When loading
MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
{
    FileStream^ fs = File::OpenRead(L"encrypted.txt");
    Decrypt(fr, ms);
    delete fs;
}

ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin::Begin);

//Later, read from the memory stream
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, how would I do that? I have tried that too but couldnt figure out the right way of doing it, seems like I missed something really small, but still.. Would be helpful if you could give me a headstart, thanks.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed you're using native C++ I/O classes instead of managed I/O classes. Sorting this out will take some time.

Comment: I added a code sample. I didn't try to compile it, but it's the basic idea.

Comment: This helped me a lot! I get 2 kind of error but it seems like I can bypass them somehow.. Here are my errors:... Error 2 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'System::String ^' c:\c++\encryptanddecryptfiletest\encryptanddecryptfiletest\Form1.h 211 and the other one: Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::IO::FileStream ^' to 'System::IO::MemoryStream ^' c:\c++\encryptanddecryptfiletest\encryptanddecryptfiletest\Form1.h 200
... Even thought I get these errors I can bypass them and make the program run, but could this be any future problems? o.o

Comment: `Convert::ToString()` will solve the first error. The second error can probably be solved by the knowledge that both classes inherit the `Stream` class.

Comment: PS: Keep in mind that `Char` and `char` are two different types. The former, `System::Char`, is equivalent to a `wchar_t` (16-bit character). The latter is just a signed byte.

Comment: Alright, fixed the first error, the other error I guess I can ignore it ^^ Thanks for the help :)